# Data is not getting loaded in Angular view but present in the console log

Tags: angular, view

Here component is subscribing the data from service and i am clearly seeing the data inside the subscribe scope but because of some reason ng on init is getting loaded before the subscription and that is why I am not getting the data in the view.Can any one help me hoe to solve this.

Student Service

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

  students=[];
  // I HAVE MY API
  //REMOVED THIS FOR SECURITY PURPOSE
  baseUrl="";

  getStudents(){
     return this.http.get<GetResponseStudent>(this.baseUrl+"students").pipe(
       map(
         response => {
           this.students=response.students

           return this.students;
          }
     )
     );
  }

}

interface GetResponseStudent{
    status:true,
    students:Student[]
}


//StudentComponent

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.scss']
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  students:Student[]=[];
  constructor(
    private studentService:StudentService,
    private router:Router,

  ) {
   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.studentService.students.subscribe(
    //   data => {
    //    this.students=data;
    // });

    this.studentService.getStudents().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.students=data;
        console.log(this.students);
      }
    )

   console.log(this.students);
  }
}
```

Comment: For the view to access you have to initialize your variables first and then make any changes you want and the DOM will load the new change, do this in your constructor:

this.students = []

Comment: Please add code instead of adding images. It will be easier to read and answer the question.

Comment: I initiated like this before but thats not changing the result.And stuckted almost four hourse now.In normal scenario this should have loaded.I don't know whats wrong here.I am relatively new in angular.

Comment: @ArifurRahman Can you please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @ShivakumarN.R took some time while formatting.I have given the  text version.Can you help me now to find the issue?

Comment: @ArifurRahman Can you refer to the answer I have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [**ChangeDetectorRef**](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

e.g:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from 
'@angular/core';
 constructure(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

someMethod() {
this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```